# Python File Copying on SMB Network Share

Tags: python, networking, server, smb, file-copying

I have a question regarding file copying over a network with Python. I recently created a script for my department at work to be able to drag and drop files and have them copied and renamed from the source location (on a network drive) to the user specified location (also mostly on a network drive but sometimes user's desktop). The problem I am having is that randomly the script will **not** initially output all of the files that the user wanted it too. If 5 copies are supposed to be made, sometimes only 3 or 4 will actually output. If the same file(s) is dropped again with the same options it usually outputs the rest of the files no problem.

This is confusing to me because of the inconsistency of it. If it happened every time or **didn't** fix itself after re-dropping I would chalk it up to being a logical error in my script, but that doesn't seem to apply here since it is just a simple copy command. I have tried the following 3 copy commands (separately) and they all produce this result randomly.

```
os.system('echo f | xcopy /f /y "{source}" "{target}"'.format(source=source, target=target))
shutil.copyfile(source, target)
shutil.copy2(source, target)
```

I have kind of just figured it was just an issue with our network, like maybe the script is sending copy commands faster than the network can process them, but I don't know enough about networking to know if that's even possible. ***So could this issue just be an issue with our network setup or is there a better method for copying multiple files at once over a network with Python to ensure consistency?*** For the record our network is an SMB Network Share and the files are usually copied from one mapdrive to another (or user's desktop).

This is driving me crazy because the users keep complaining about it. Any advice that could be given would be extremely helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have the script check whether each file was copied successfully and re-try the failed ones.

Comment: Hmmm. That's true. I do have it currently checking if they are exporting and it let's the user know if they aren't. But it doesn't retry to copy. Thanks I will try that!